# Getting disconnections on wifi

Tags: wireless, networking, vpn

I'm running 14.04LTS and this is the first time using a wireless card on my computer. In my previous residence, I was able to have my computer connected via ethernet. However now that I have moved, this is not possible and didn't think it would be a huge issue.

I'm using an Alfa AWUS036NH wireless card to connect to the router in the living room. The router is on the other end of the house, but I have no problem connecting and have a decent signal. I try to keep a connection to my VPN almost 100% of the time, but I've seen it disconnect multiple times. It appears to be doing it at random. I've seen it work perfectly for over an hour, and then I've also seen it disconnect in less than 10 minutes.

It wouldn't be a big deal because it seems like it stays connected to the router, but drops the VPN connection, because it then instantly says "Connected to Wireless Network". I have seen it briefly disconnect me when not even using the VPN service, so I'm guessing this is something related to software, or my wireless card?

Comment: This is apparently an Realtek RTL8187 card. The disconnects might be a bug, the only way to verify is to test the system under another operating system (Windows). You should report it on Launchpad. You might have some luck with an updated kernel or driver.

Comment: Bug report is probably [Bug #1268833](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1268833)